# ADL cannot find overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, argument-dependent-lookup

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    bool valid(T a)
    { return is_valid(a); }
};

bool is_valid(int)
{ return true; }

int main()
{
    S<int> s;
    s.valid(0);
}
```

VS compiles this sample fine while GCC says:

> error: 'is_valid' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations
>   were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation
>   [-fpermissive]

I'm not sure why ADL cannot find `bool is_valid(int)` as it's defined before `S<int> s` instantiation. I suppose it's correct behaviour as Clang says the same. So I tried to add

```
template<typename T>
bool is_valid(T);
```

at the beginning to use function overloading and now [Godbolt compiles it fine by Clang or GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/DkP5C6), but not local GCC compilation or [on Ideone](http://ideone.com/EetaX7).

How can I use ADL in this case to provide function definition after template declaration (GCC)? Bonus: why Godbolt compiles the last sample?

### Solution:

Thanks to the accepted answer, I figured out that the problem is that ADL treats primitive types specifically. This helped me to end up with following solution that uses forward declaration of templated function which can be overloaded for user-defined types or specialised for primitive types.

```
template<typename T>
bool is_valid(T);

template<typename T>
struct S
{
        bool valid(T a)
        { return is_valid(a); }
};

template<>
bool is_valid<int>(int)
{ return true; }

struct User_data
{};

bool is_valid(User_data)
{ return true; }

int main()
{
        S<int> s_primitive;
        s_primitive.valid(0);
        S<User_data> s_user_data;
        s_user_data.valid(User_data{});
}
```

[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L9XNZeUlLZZZswW2)

Comment: Are you not allowed to forward declare `is_valid(int)`?

Comment: @AndyG: `int` here is just an example, the template is instantiated for many different types and it would be inconvenient if possible to forward declare overloads of `is_valid` for all of them in a single common place

Comment: I see. Updated my answer. You're probably not going to like it, though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to forward declare `is_valid(int)`:

```
bool is_valid(int);
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    bool valid(T a)
    { return is_valid(a); }
};
```

ADL for fundamental types (like `int`) produces an empty set of namespaces and classes to consider, so when you pass `0` into `S::valid`, you're not bringing in the outer `is_valid(int)`. Forward declaration effectively lets the template know the function exists.

Regarding the behavior you see in Godbolt... there must be some extra work being done by the compiler explorer because the same gcc and clang versions it is allegedly using do not work on any other compiler (like Wandbox)

---

If you *really* want ADL to work, then you need to modify the free function `is_valid` such that ADL is an option. My recommendation is to declare a helper struct `ADL_Helper` in the same scope as all your free-floating `is_valid` functions, then `S::is_valid` will pass an instance:

```
struct ADL_Helper{};

template<typename T>
struct S
{
    bool valid(T a)
    { return is_valid(a, ADL_Helper{}); }
};

bool is_valid(int, ADL_Helper)
{ return true; }

int main()
{
    S<int> s;
    s.valid(0);
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YwG3WyV8nIiRMKsc)

Comment: +1: I checked and yeah, ADL doesn't find overloads only for primitive types. Didn't know it treats them specifically. I ended up with a little bit different approach (in the edit), please let me know if you see any problem with it.

Comment: OP's alternative code (with the forward-declared template) will compile but not link. Godbolt doesn't do linking (it has no need to) unless you tell it to compile to binary and disassemble.

Comment: I thought `is_valid(a);` depends on type `T` that isn't unknown until the template is instantiated, which is at the end of the translation unit.  By the end of this translation unit, I thought `bool is_valid(int)` is in scope.  No?  I am sure I missed something because compiler says so.